# How do I preserve newlines when using filter_var(var, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)?

Tags: php, filter-var

I have a web form with a textarea for street address. The expectation is the user will enter two or three lines of text, hitting the Enter key for newlines within the textarea data.

When I submit the form, PHP sends the form data via mail(), with the related $_POST variable as part of the email body.

I'm sanitizing the user input with filter_var(), but in the resulting email the newlines seem to be getting stripped out of the textarea, and the lines end up being concatenated without even so much as a space between them.

How do I preserve newlines while still sanitizing the textarea input for email delivery?

Relevant HTML:

```
<textarea name="addr"></textarea>
```

Relevant PHP:

```
$em_body = 'Address:' . PHP_EOL . filter_var($_POST['addr'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: Why use a `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` filter on an address value?!

Comment: From the [Sanitize filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) PHP manual: "_Remove all characters except letters, digits and !#$%&'*+-=?^_`{|}~@.[]_"

Comment: The use of `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` is for sanitizing **an email address**, not for sanitizing any and all data that you may want to email. (If you are looking for protection from email header injections via form submission etc. that's a whole other chapter to study. This is not it.)